# Limit of convergent sequence of contraction maps

Tags: functions, uniform-convergence, lipschitz-functions

Let $f_n$ a sequence of contractions on a metric space $(Y,d)$, with a Lipschitz constant $0<\lambda<1$. Suppose that for all $y\in Y$ the sequence $f_n(y)$ converges to $f(y)$. Then $F$ is also a contraction with Lipschitz constant $\lambda$.

My proof is as follows:
\begin{align*}
d(f(y_1),f(y_2)) \leq d(f(y_1),f_n(y_1)) + d(f_n(y_1),f_n(y_2)) + d(f_n(y_2),f(y_2)) \leq d(f(y_1),f_n(y_1)) +\lambda\cdot d(y_1,y_2) + d(f_n(y_2),f(y_2))
\end{align*}
Then taking $n\to\infty$ I get $d(f(y_1),f(y_2))\leq \lambda\cdot d(y_1,y_2)$, so $f$ is a contraction with Lipschitz constant $\lambda$.

Is the proof correct? Or do I need $f_n\to f$ uniformly?

Comment: I assume that $(Y,d)$ is the range of $f_n'$s. Then your proof is correct and you don't need uniform convergence (since you are just based on the implication: if $x_n $ converges to $x$ in metric $d$, then $d(x_n,z)\rightarrow d(x,z)$ for all $z\in X$).